# data not inserting into firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The code executes without any error but firebase realtime database shows :-

testapp-a212c-default-rtdb: null

I have created the model class User. How do I insert data into firebase realtime database?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    writeNewUser("123","asdf","asdf@gmail.com");
 }

 public void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation?

Comment: Yes i tried task.isSuccessful() inside  OnComopleteListener(). But the control doesn't seem to go inside the listener.

Comment: So is onComplete even triggered?

Comment: No. the addOnCompleteListener() event is not trigerred at all.

Answer (score 2):

To get a reference to a database other than a us-central1 default dstabase, you must pass the database URL to getInstance() (or Kotlin+KTX database()) . For a us-central1 default database, you can call getInstance() (or database) without arguments.

I was using SouthAsia Database.

Comment: I had spent so much time trying to figure out what is wrong, this answer was what i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: this is a perfect answer . thanks Gaurav Thapa

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to insert `stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,` in main.dart file. Which is ended up with uploading data to firebase Real Time Database.